# Дочерние элементы в префабе обьекта

Tags: c#, unity3d, prefabs

Есть моделька генератор. Создал Префаб, вышло так что в префабе 10 дочерних элементов.
Есть код, который обращается в `MeshRenderer` и меняет материал дочернего объекта.

```
public class Unit : MonoBehaviour {

    public Material Ghost;
    public Material GhostNone;
    public Material Normal;

    string tagCreate = "CreateUnit";
    string tagComplete = "CompleteUnit";

    void Update ()
    {
        if (gameObject.tag == tagCreate)
        {
            gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<MeshRenderer>().material = Ghost;
        }

         if((gameObject.tag == tagCreate)&&(GlobalVar.onTriggerUnit == true))
        {
            gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<MeshRenderer>().material = GhostNone;
        }         
    }
    void OnTriggerEnter ()
    {
        GlobalVar.onTriggerUnit = true;
    }
    private void OnTriggerExit()
    {
        GlobalVar.onTriggerUnit = false;      
    }
}
```

Проблема в том, что мне надо, чтобы это действовало на всех дочерних элементах, а не только на первом.

Comment: Я планирую добавить еще разные объекты, с разным количеством дочерних элементов, можно как то сделать костяк этого кода чтобы применялось к разным объектам?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вся ваша проблема в том, что вы испльзуете метод `GetComponentInChildren<>()`, который возвращает первый найденный компонент в иерархии, используя поиск в глубину. Об этом написано в [документации](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponentInChildren.html).

Для того, чтобы получить все компоненты на всех дочерних элементах используйте метод [GetComponentsInChildren<>()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponentsInChildren.html), который вернет вам массив всех нужных компонентов.

И получится следующий подход:

```
var meshRenderers = gameObject.GetComponentsInChildren<MeshRenderer>();
foreach( var meshRenderer in meshRenderers)
     meshRenderer.material = Ghost;
```

Comment: @Игорь, пожалуйста. Если ответ помог вам решить проблему, отметьте его как правильный и тем самым закроете вопрос

Comment: @Игорь, только ради Святого Компилятора, уберите постоянный ПОИСК дочерних компонентов (`GetComponentsInChildren<MeshRenderer>()`) из каждого кадра (`Update()`). Заполните список "meshRenderers" один раз (н-р, в `Start()`) и обновляйте его при необходимости.

Comment: Спасибо, я просто начинающий в unity3d)